# Finding the ROW value in an Excel WB using Powershell based on the MAX value

Tags: excel, powershell

I have an Excel workbook that has values from F13 to F40, these values change every Powershell Job run we do.

I need to find the Top 3 values in the range of F13 - F40 and I need to get the Row Number of each of the three valuesToo
So far I can get the 3 values with this Code in Powershell

```
$EXCEL = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$EXCEL.visible = $false
$basefinalwb = $EXCEL.workbooks.open("C:\relax\Book1.xlsx")
$basefinalws = $basefinalwb.worksheets.Item("Current Results")
$MAX1 = $basefinalws.cells.item(1,1).Formula = "=LARGE(F13:F40, 1)"
$MAX2 = $basefinalws.cells.item(2,1).Formula = "=LARGE(F13:F40, 2)"
$MAX3 = $basefinalws.cells.item(3,1).Formula = "=LARGE(F13:F40, 3)"
$MAX11 = $basefinalws.cells.item(1,1).value2
$MAX21 = $basefinalws.cells.item(2,1).value2
$MAX31 = $basefinalws.cells.item(3,1).value2
Write-host Max11 is $max11
Write-host Max21 is $max21
Write-host Max31 is $max31
```

---

```
The Results are this:
Max11 is 0.112570356472795
Max21 is 0.097560975609756
Max31 is 0.0881801125703564
```

Now I need to figure out which Row each of those Values came from

So I have tried this code and it returns blank

```
   $Cell2 = $basefinalws.range("F1","F40").find("$MAX21")
   $Cell2.Value2
   $Cell2.Row
   $Cell2
```

In my testing I even pulled the Value on the Cell the number came from and they match .. I just cannot figure out why "find" isn't working.

Now the only thing I can think of is that all the values in the F column are from Formulas =(D13-C13)/C13 but the above code does grab the value of the cell just fine it just can't re-find it so I can get the Row Number

If anyone knows where I am going wrong, help is appreciated or maybe an easier way to accomplish the task?

Thank you!

Comment: `$MAX21` shouldn't be enclosed in quotation marks.

Comment: Thank you but sadly with or without quotes it still returns blank

Comment: Is a formula a possibility? I.e. something like `=ROW(INDEX(F13:F40,MATCH(A1,F13:F40,0)))`, which you could write in cell B1 or A4 maybe, and then read its `.value2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are already finding the 3 top values with the `LARGE` formula, a possibly easier option  than `Find` could be using `ROW`, `INDEX` and `MATCH` formulas somewhere else on the worksheet... something like this (tested with the formula `=(D13-C13)/C13` in `F13:F40`.

```
...
$ROW1 = $basefinalws.cells.item(4,1).Formula = "=ROW(INDEX(F13:F40,MATCH(A1,F13:F40,0)))"
$ROW2 = $basefinalws.cells.item(5,1).Formula = "=ROW(INDEX(F13:F40,MATCH(A2,F13:F40,0)))"
$ROW3 = $basefinalws.cells.item(6,1).Formula = "=ROW(INDEX(F13:F40,MATCH(A3,F13:F40,0)))"
...
$ROW11 = $basefinalws.cells.item(4,1).value2
$ROW21 = $basefinalws.cells.item(5,1).value2
$ROW31 = $basefinalws.cells.item(6,1).value2
...
Write-Host Row11 is $Row11
Write-Host Row21 is $Row21
Write-Host Row31 is $Row31
```